# Does Volume Purchasing apply to In-App purchases?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have designed an application which contains in App purchasing. I have also read about Volume Purchasing introduced by Apple recently. I want to know if there is Volume Purchasing for In App purchases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Volume Purchasing just applies to buying the the app.

http://images.apple.com/business/docs/VPP_Business_Guide_US.pdf

http://www.apple.com/itunes/education/

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/opportunities/